# How to use before test suite and after test suite in one test in testRigor?

Tags: test-suite, testrigor

I am using testRigor for Android application. I have testcases for before test suite and after test suite.
I added login test script in before test suite and logout script added in after test suite.
One Testcase for use login functions,so I can't use this three testsuite in one testing process

Answer (score 1):

Because all of test cases for [testRigor](https://testrigor.com) are executed in parallel, the way "Before test suite" works is it is executed before all other test cases. That also means that logout is unnecessary because every test case is execute on a new server in a new fresh incognito browser.

To achieve what you are looking for you need to specify app's the username and password in Settings/Authentication, and then start all of your test cases from the built-in command `login`